# "Filename or extension too long" for move, but it isn't

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, path

I'd appreciate some insight as this is driving me nuts.

- I have a folder on a network share: `\\host.example.com\Share\Path\Container1\Folder`
- I am trying to move that folder to a new location on the same share: `\\host.example.com\Share\Path\Container2\Folder`
- I'm using the following command to do this: `move "\\host.example.com\Share\Path\Container1\Folder" "\\host.example.com\Share\Path\Container2\Folder"`
- This move command is executed by our build system.

...and the move command fails in the build system because the "The filename or extension is too long." (I've checked multiple times - **all** paths involved are below 100 ASCII characters.)
However, if I execute the **exact same** command by hand it's executed right away without a hitch.

Now here's the really weird part: if I remove the domain name part from the FQDN like so:

```
move "\\host\Share\Path\Container1\Folder" "\\host\Share\Path\Container2\Folder"
```

then it works from the build system as well.

What gives?

Comment: What do you mean by build system? perhaps it's incorectly identifying the dots in domain as start of file extension?

Comment: The build system (QuickBuild in this case) is executing the command as is (as a windows shell command) - if anyone is misidentifying the dots that would be the move command. In that case I'd expect it to break when run from the command line as well though.

Comment: D'oh! I'm of course using backslashes in my command not forward slashes - I've mistyped all my examples. Will edit in a sec.

Comment: About KB112744: that seems to be a Windows NT issue, so quite old (we're running Windows Server 2012 R2), and would also mean that the same command fails from the command line as well.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Are these machines in a domain? Is Distributed File System in use on the machine hosting the share?

Comment: Look over this as it suggests for Windows Server 2012 stating: "**Note This problem can also occur when you try to copy files or folders from Volume Shadow Copy Service snapshots if the file or folder length in the snapshot exceeds the maximum path length.**" --> Here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891362 . . . This may be related to DFS and VSS both as Twisty I think is suggesting as another potential why you see this with UNC path in the MOVE command.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately: 1) Both paths (and all files involved) are way shorter than MAX_PATH. 2) We have the updates installed suggested in KB2891362. 3) As far as I'm aware we're not using DFS (but I'll verify that tomorrow). 4) Yes, the machines are in a domain.

Comment: Look into using the `/MOVE` option of Robocopy.exe instead. Has more control and logging.